# Getting rid of comma on last element of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that loops through music tracks but I need to remove the comma from the last element of the array, can someone help?

```
<?php foreach ($bucket_contents as $file){ $fname = $file['name']; $furl = "http://".$isdHtml5Bucket.".s3.amazonaws.com/".urlencode($fname);

if(preg_match("/\.mp3$/i", $furl)) { ?>
    {
            name:"<?php echo basename($fname); ?>",
            mp3:"<?php echo $furl; ?>"

        },
<?php }else{ ?>
        {
            name:"<?php echo basename($fname); ?>",
            m4a:"<?php echo $furl; ?>"

        },<?php } } ?>
```

And here is the output of the array.

```
    {
        name:"bassline",
        m4a:"http://suyssamuelarawaeast.s3.amazonaws.com/warehouse%2Fbassline%2F"

    },
    {
        name:"Project Bassline - Drop The Pressure (Jack Beats Rinsed Out Remix).mp3",
        mp3:"http://suyssamuelarawaeast.s3.amazonaws.com/warehouse%2Fbassline%2FProject+Bassline+-+Drop+The+Pressure+%28Jack+Beats+Rinsed+Out+Remix%29.mp3"

    },
        {
        name:"deadmau5 vs jelo   the reward is cheese.mp3",
        mp3:"http://suyssamuelarawaeast.s3.amazonaws.com/warehouse%2Fdeadmau5+vs+jelo+++the+reward+is+cheese.mp3"

    },
    {
        name:"vocal",
        m4a:"http://suyssamuelarawaeast.s3.amazonaws.com/warehouse%2Fvocal%2F"

    },      
            {
        name:"Thin Ice",
        free:true,
        mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-10-Thin-ice.mp3",
        oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-10-Thin-ice.ogg"
    },
```

If you scroll to the last element of the array you can see a comma is output.
I really need to remove this comma from the last element of the array.

Thanks

Comment: Also, I sure hope you have permission from the copyright holders!

Comment: Someone else can finish the formatting...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

pass your string through [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) and specify the comma in the charlist as a removable character:

```
$str = rtrim($str, ',');
```

**Edit**

Or... perhaps this approach (not tested):

```
$songs = array();

foreach ($bucket_contents as $file) { 

    $fname = $file['name'];
    $furl  = "http://".$isdHtml5Bucket.".s3.amazonaws.com/".urlencode($fname);

    $type = preg_match("/\.mp3$/i", $furl) ? 'mp3' : 'm4a'; 
    $songs[] = sprintf('{ name: %s, %s: %s }', $fname, $type, $furi); 
}

echo implode(',', $songs);
```

Comment: As he is outputting directly, rather than creating a string, he would either need to alter his code to create a string or use output buffering to get the output back, then `rtrim()` and reoutput.

Comment: +1 Nice approach, providing he does not want the whitespace formatted.

Comment: Of course! He may, in which case `sprintf("{\n\tname: %s,\n\t%s: %s\n}", ... )` and `implode(",\n", $songs)` should do the trick.

Comment: +1 Good approach, assuming building a temporary array isn't a problem. Nitpicking: A comma to separate arguments to implode() is missing.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Cleaned up the code. This one doesn't use a temporary array, like the other answers.

I don't see how that code could produce that output, since he final output block has fields in it you aren't printing. That aside, something like this is probably what you want (untested):

```
<?php

$comma = '';
foreach ($bucket_contents as $file) {
  $fname = $file['name'];
  $furl = "http://".$isdHtml5Bucket.".s3.amazonaws.com/" . urlencode($fname);
  $ext = preg_match("/\.mp3$/i") ? "mp3" : "m4a";

  printf('%s{\nname:"%s",\n%s:"%s"\n}', $comma, $fname, $type, $furi);
  $comma = ",\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: There would still be a comma at the end.

Comment: @Neddy: No, the comma is printed in front of each block, except the first.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

foreach($bucket_contents as $file){ 
    $fname = $file['name']; 
    $furl = "http://".$isdHtml5Bucket.".s3.amazonaws.com/".urlencode($fname);
    $ext = preg_match("/\.mp3$/i") ? "mp3" : "m4a";

    $t[] = '{name:"'.basename($fname).'",'.$ext.':"'.$furl.'"}';
}

echo implode(',',$t);
```

There you go. Much nicer :)